# perl get session cookie

Tags: perl, session, cookies

is not work for some cookie

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Request::Common qw(GET);
use HTTP::Cookies;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;

# Define user agent type
$ua->agent('Mozilla/4.0');

# Cookies
$ua->cookie_jar(
    HTTP::Cookies->new(
        file => 'mycookies.txt',
        autosave => 1
    )
);

# Request object
my $req = GET 'http://www.google.com';

# Make the request
my $res = $ua->request($req);

# Check the response
if ($res->is_success) {
    print $res->content;
} else {
    print $res->status_line . "\n";
}

exit 0;
```

when cookie is like this ( from firebug )

```
name  value    
PREF  ID=00349dffbc142a77:FF=0:LD=en:CR=2:TM=1311217451:LM=1311217451:S=QKw9G4vAwl19Me4g
```

mycookies.txt is

```
#LWP-Cookies-1.0
Set-Cookie3:  
PREF="ID=00349dffbc142a77:FF=0:TM=1311217451:LM=1311217451:S=QKw9G4vAwl19Me4g";
path="/"; domain=.google.com; path_spec; expires="2013-07-20 03:04:11Z"; version=0
```

but for some site when cookie look like this

```
name         value
verify       test
guest_id     131099303870438180
PHPSESSID    7s99iq1qcamooidrop4iehcv32
```

nothing in mycookies.txt

how to fix it.

thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first cookie is a domain cookie with expiry in the future. So it gets written to the cookie jar.

The second cookie is a session cookie, and expires when the program closes. It gets kept in memory, and does not get written to the jar.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is a bit late.  The checked answer only describes why you have this problem.  To actually "fix" the problem you need to look into the  ignore_discard parameter for HTTP::Cookies.

Comment: That fixed my issue as well to add `ignore_discard => 1` in the `HTTP::Cookies->new` parameters